# How to retrieve one record at a time from Dictionary Class in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I am inserting records in Dictionary and while retrieving i am using code something like this:

```
System.out.println(newLine + "Items in the dictionary..." + dict + newLine);
```

and it is giving me result as:

```
Items in the dictionary...{pa=1234567890, abcd=8976543245}
```

but i want it in different manner. i want to access each record and field separately.
I want result something like this:

```
Name     Contact
pa       1234567890
abcd     8976543245
```

Comment: You may already know this, but just in case: `Dictionary` is an outdated class, and you should use `Map` and its implementations if circumstances allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary` has `keys` method to get keys you can iterate over than and get values

```
    Enumeration<String> e = dictionary.keys();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(e.nextElement());
    }
```

If it's a custom collection, you can write your own `Iterator`

If it's a `Map` or `HashTable`

You can iterate over dictionary using

Example

```
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : dict.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
    for (String key : dict.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " " + dict.get(key));
    }
```

In Java8

```
    dict.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

`Dictionary` has `keys` method to get keys you can iterate over than and get values

**EDIT**

change your declaration to

`Hashtable<String, String> dict = new Hashtable<String, String>();` so that you'll get the methods to iterate over `HashTable`

Comment: This code is for  `Map`, not `Dictionary` — which the asker may in fact be using, but if it is indeed `Dictionary`, there’s no `entrySet()` method.

Comment: for (String key : dict.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " " + dict.get(key));
    }
for this it is giving error:  The method keySet() is undefined for the type 
  Dictionary<String,String>

Comment: what should i do for Dictionary?

Comment: what to write in loop to go on to the next recoed each time

Comment: can you provide the code what type of dictionary and how you initialized ?

Comment: Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Hashtable<String, String>();

Comment: change it to `Hashtable<String, String> dict = new Hashtable<String, String>();` you'll get the methods to iterate, updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93029/discussion-between-parag-bhingre-and-uuid).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate over `dict.keys()`, then retrieve the value for each key using `dict.get()`.